# Is a 'normally' convergent sequence still convergent in a metric space which barely excludes its 'normal' limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

For example, suppose

$$ x_n = \frac 1n \\ X = (0, 1)$$

Is $x_n$ convergent in $X$?

---

My guess would be no, since there exists no $x \in X$ which $x_n$ approaches; $x_n$ will eventually surpass any given $\bar x \in X$.  Assuming I'm right, is there a better reason for this to be so?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Note that $X = (0, 1)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. If $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ converged in $X$, then something like $x_n = n$ would converge in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: ... since any potential limit of $x_n=n$ would also be surpassed by the sequence.  Gotcha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upshot is, if its "normal" limit isn't in the space, then the sequence doesn't converge **in the space**.

It's often important to make such a distinction (between convergence in a space and convergence in some overlying larger space). For instance, your example sequence shows that $(0,1)$ with the usual metric isn't a complete metric space (if you know the sequence is Cauchy), nor is it compact in any equivalent metric (since the sequence has no convergent subsequence).